# "Images as Planes" (texture with transparency) + Cycles, plane still visible after render

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have quite a dense scene, with a lighting from behind through fog. I like the mood very much.
Here is an EEVEE render (16 samples):

[image]

When I render this with cycles (512 samples) it looks like this:

[image]

One can clearly see the planes, where the images of the textures are placed on.

Before the scene was that dense, I made a cycles render with the same settings and got this:

[image]

I'm keen about knowing more about the effect in cycles. I believe, because the more dense scene leaves less less light will reach the planes in front of the camera and this will cause the effect.
But I wonder why the transparent plane parts are affected by the rendering at all...? Because they are... transparent!?!
I wonder if insanely high sample values in cycles would improve the situation or if I just have to have a more powerful light.
In the end this should be an animation of at least 300 frames.

(like here in EEVEE: https://youtu.be/f4u1mUMdepI)

Edit: This is my shader node tree for the "Image as plane" object of one of my flowers:

[image]

Edit: This is the image on a plane that I use as texture. I cannot see any non transparency on that plane though...

[image]

Edit: Well, maybe there is something, because the grid does not shine through as bright as it is besides the plane. Looks as if I made some fundamental mistake by creating that image for my texture...

Comment: Just to be sure, did you plug the alpha output of the image texture into the fac input of a mix shader, with a transparent shader on the upper socket, or did you do something else?

Comment: See my edit above.

I have not done anything by myself except for adding an "image as planes" object, which then asks me for the image to put on the plane. The nodes above are then automatically added.

Since I'm just at the beginning of my Blender journey, it looks reasonable to me because of the connected alpha channel. Could you evaluate a little bit on the "fac input" you mention?

What I think is important here is that the rendering result of the plane changed with increasing density of the scene. If you see the image with the relatively empty scene, all planes are invisible.

Comment: That sould do the trick, but I never use the Alpha socket of the Principled BSDF myself, so I'm not entirely sure. It may be that the alpha channel isn't completely transparent where it should be. I'm just sitting down to dinner, but I'll post an answer later with what I usually do. I cannot guarantee that it'll solve your problem. If the alpha channel isn't fully transparent, it won't help. If you're open to sharing the texture you're using, that may well give some insight.

Comment: It might be an interesting experiment to throw a converter->colorRamp into the alpha line and pull the black and white knobs towards the center. If it is an alpha channel that isn't fully transparent this might fix it...

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try with the color ramp! I will also share the texture in its current state, No problem. I just have to return home from work. The one question that bothers me ist the fact that the plane ist visible in the dense scene but not in the previous one. In between both renders I have not touched the texture plane at all and both are rendered with 512 samples.

Comment: Unfortunately the image itself is not contained in your .blend. You'd need to either pack it into the .blend, or upload it separately somewhere. To pack it, click _File_ -> _External Data_ -> _Pack Resources_.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm such a noob... I updated the file. It should contain the image now.

Comment: No need to apologise. You can't know that which you never learned.

Comment: I just examined you image, and it seems to be fine. It has 29 different levels in the alpha channel, the lowest one being 0, and the highest one being 1. The ones in between are just around the edges of the leaves and petals, which is reasonable, to reduce the appearance of it being an overlaid image rather than a real flower. I'll look at your .blend as soon as I have the time, to see if I can figure out why this is happening. It's around 7pm where I am, and I may not have time to look closer until tomorrow.

Comment: Haha, It's 7pm here as well. My Blender time has just started. This evening I have nothing else to do. What tool did you use to analyze my image, in order to see the 29 different levels in the alpha channel?

Comment: I unpacked the image and saved it to disk, then opened it in GIMP and separated the alpha channel into a greyscale layer. Then I simply used _Colors_ -> _Info_ -> _Colorcube analysis_. The comment section is not meant for discussions like this. I suggest you try the solution suggested by @PierreDucos in his answer, as this may well do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This problem may have less to do with your shader-tree, and more to do with your *render* settings. Blender's Cycles renderer is built for realism, but by nature, Cycles is *still* a little bit of a biased engine, to avoid obscene render times on simple scenes.

Let's tell Cycles to put a little more effort where it's needed:

Go to the "Render Properties" tab, *(looks like a small camera icon)* and click on "Light Paths".

[image]

[image]

Under Light Paths, locate the section that reads "Transparent".

[image]

Change your "Transparent" Light bounces from "8" to a higher number, like "32" or "64".

(I recommend finding the *lowest value* that works for your scene, and rounding it up high.)

*Good luck! Happy Blending!*

Comment: Thanks for that hint! I'm currently evaluating but I struggle with render times of 5 minutes per frame @ just 64 samples (instead of 512 in my initial images). So far I have checked values of 32 and 64 in "transparent light bounces" but I have not seen any improvement, yet... I will tweak a little bit around and post the results later.

Comment: Hello! I am sorry that this did not answer your question. Could you re-pack your .blend file, and send it once more? I will try to solve this problem more thoroughly, but I will need to dig into the issue firsthand. (If you need help packing .blend files, here is a simple tutorial: ( https://youtu.be/SqwEGDIPTY8 )

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry about the delay, but here's the answer I promised.
This image shows how I usually use transparency from images:
[image: Nodes for transparency]

I did a quick test with the *Alpha* socket of the *Principled BSDF*, and it seems to give the exact same result, though the setup in the image also works with shaders that don't have an *Alpha* socket. I doubt if the setup described here will actually make a difference, but one point of difference (that may or may not matter at all), is that I always change the interpolation of image textures to *Cubic*. I also explicitly include the UV, but that really shouldn't matter, as for image textures the default UV map is used implicitly. My best guess is that the alpha channel of your texture isn't fully transparent. You could, as @RonJensen suggested, insert a *Color Ramp* to make sure the alpha value actually is 0 where it should be.

The *Mix Shader* mixes two shaders such that if the *Fac* is 0, it's equivalent to using only the shader that is connected to the upper *Shader* socket, and if the *Fac* is 1, it's equivalent to using only the shader that is connected to the lower *Shader* socket, and anything between 0 and 1 mixes the two shaders correspondingly.

Why your problem doesn't occur in Eevee, I honestly cannot say for certain, but I seem to vaguely remember having been told that Eevee only has on or off for transparency, no in-betweens, unless explicitly enabled. This would make sense from a performance point of view, but accuracy would of course suffer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! To clarify my point: Image number 1 in my post above is Eeevee. The next two images are both cycles, rendered with 512 samples. So the image which contains the rocks and the dense vegetation has this strange texture effect, but not the image that only contains 2 trees is totally fine. This one bugs me the most: Both are cycles with the same image textures of my flowers, but the dense scene does not render correctly (as Eevee does in image number 1 of my post). Again, I post my texture as soon as I got hands on my computer...

Comment: Just another comment that refers more to your answer: I really do appreciate all the little details you provided like the description of your node tree. I must admit I don't fully understand all of it, but at least I have some hints to further investigate. Also, the point that Eevee has a default setting of on or off for transparency is a good one to have in mind. I'm really interested in such background knowledge but I haven't found a thorough documentation of Eevee and cycles, yet.

Comment: @Kiamur I got that first image was rendered with Eevee, and the other two with Cycles. I can't offer an explanation, but one guess would be that it gets more visible if there's stuff behind it. Think of a pair of slightly tinted glasses; if you hold them up in thin air, the tint is close to invisible, but if you hold them up facing an obstacle, the tint gets more pronounced. But I have a hard time believing that would account for such a great difference with your renders. You could try to crank up the value for _Transparent_ under _Light Paths_ in the render properties.

Comment: Please find that texture in my post above. I'm looking forward to your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I'm extensively embarrassed...

As Pierre suggested, I wanted to upload my blender scene. It was way too big and so I started to reduce the objects in it.

As mentioned initially, the effect occurred when the density of the scene increased. So I thought, at one point, the effect will disappear, while I reduce objects...
In the end I had less objects as in my initial question, but the effect was still there.

Then I saw it... I somehow, accidentally doubled the plane on which all the particle textures were placed... By doing this, I inflicted the effect by myself because now, planes were just on top of each other and I cannot blame cycles for running wild here.
I'm sorry that I wasted everybodys time!

To make it clear, here are some before/after screenshots:
[image]

[image]

However... as shown in blue, there are still artifacts of the plane visible. They disappear more and more, when I increase the overall render samples. The lightpath setting that Pierre suggested does not help here, either.
I still wonder why a transparent plane has such effect in cycles...

Anyway, I still tried to upload the file for you to examine (the "blue circle" effect), but I cannot reduce the file size under 49MB and I'm only allowed to upload 30MB.
Since the main question is answered, I think this question can be considered as closed.
Thanks everybody! I learned a lot!